# How to make this class to add on every click

Tags: javascript

If the checkbox is not check and if the button is clicked then the shake effect is added to the checkbox div, but it doesn't work every time the button is clicked. How to make it so that it happen on every button click if the checkbox is not checked. classList.add only adds the class once so I used toggle.
[JsFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/vcrjzq3e/).

```html
<style>
  .face {
    animation: shake 0.82s cubic-bezier(.36, .07, .19, .97) both;
    transform: translate3d(0, 0, 0);
    backface-visibility: hidden;
    perspective: 1000px;
  }
  
  @keyframes shake {
    10%,
    90% {
      transform: translate3d(-1px, 0, 0);
    }
    20%,
    80% {
      transform: translate3d(2px, 0, 0);
    }
    30%,
    50%,
    70% {
      transform: translate3d(-4px, 0, 0);
    }
    40%,
    60% {
      transform: translate3d(4px, 0, 0);
    }
  }
</style>
</style>

<body>

  <br>
  <br>
  <div id="termsdiv">
    <input type="checkbox" id="terms">Terms
  </div>
  <div id="privacydiv">
    <input type="checkbox" id="privacy">Privacy
  </div>
  <br>
  <a id='googlebtn' onclick='return func();' type='submit' href="http://google.com"><img src="https://staging-4.dispatchhealth.com/icons/btn_sign_in_google.png"></a>
</body>
<script>
  function func() {
    var termsCheckbox = document.getElementById("terms");
    var termsdiv = document.getElementById("termsdiv");
    var privacyCheckbox = document.getElementById("privacy");
    var privacydiv = document.getElementById("privacydiv");
    if (termsCheckbox.checked == false) {
      termsdiv.classList.toggle("face");
      // alert("You must agree to the terms");
      return false;
    }
    if (privacyCheckbox.checked == false) {
      privacydiv.classList.toggle("face");
      // alert("You must agree to the privacy");
      return false;
    }
  }
</script>
```

Comment: https://css-tricks.com/restart-css-animation/

Comment: It's because you're toggling the class on click - the animation only runs when it gets the `face` class, so every other click, when the class is removed, nothing happens.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There were two issues:

1. You're returned false in case of first checkbox isn't checked. The second checkbox wasn't checked in this case. You have to return at the end.
2. `toggle` added the class on first click an removed it on second click. Now i `add` the class and `remove` it after 820ms on click.

```js
function func() {
  var termsCheckbox = document.getElementById("terms");
  var termsdiv = document.getElementById("termsdiv");
  var privacyCheckbox = document.getElementById("privacy");
  var privacydiv = document.getElementById("privacydiv");
  var bReturnValue;
    
  if (termsCheckbox.checked === false) {  
    termsdiv.classList.add("face"); //Add Class
    setTimeout(function(){
     termsdiv.classList.remove("face"); //Remove Class after 820ms
    },820);
     bReturnValue = false; //Store return value in variabel
  }
  
  if (privacyCheckbox.checked === false) {
   privacydiv.classList.add("face");
    setTimeout(function(){
     privacydiv.classList.remove("face");
    },820);
    bReturnValue = false;
  }
  return bReturnValue; //Return return value
}
```

```css
 .face {
   animation: shake 0.82s cubic-bezier(.36, .07, .19, .97) both;
   transform: translate3d(0, 0, 0);
   backface-visibility: hidden;
   perspective: 1000px;
 }

 @keyframes shake {
   10%,
   90% {
     transform: translate3d(-1px, 0, 0);
   }
   20%,
   80% {
     transform: translate3d(2px, 0, 0);
   }
   30%,
   50%,
   70% {
     transform: translate3d(-4px, 0, 0);
   }
   40%,
   60% {
     transform: translate3d(4px, 0, 0);
   }
 }
```

```html
<br>
<br>
<div id="termsdiv">
  <input type="checkbox" id="terms">Terms
</div>
<div id="privacydiv">
  <input type="checkbox" id="privacy">Privacy
</div>
<br>
<a id='googlebtn' onclick='return func();' type='submit' href="http://google.com"><img src="http://lorempixel.com/300/100/"></a>
```

Answer (score 0):

How toggle works -->

When you click the button it is adding 'face' class to checkbox div individually which makes it shake.

When you click button again it removes the 'face' class from checkbox div which does no action.

So place a set timeout to remove the 'face' class just after adding the class, make the timeout <= shake time (which is 820 ms here)

Please check the working copy here: 
https://github.com/helloritesh000/how-to-make-this-class-to-add-on-every-click

```
if (termsCheckbox.checked == false) {
            termsdiv.classList.add("face");
            setTimeout(function(){ console.log("function func1212"); termsdiv.classList.remove("face"); }, 800);
            // alert("You must agree to the terms");
            return false;
        } 
        if(privacyCheckbox.checked == false) {
            privacydiv.classList.add("face");
            setTimeout(function(){ privacydiv.classList.remove("face"); }, 800);
            // alert("You must agree to the privacy");
            return false;
        }
```